# What does MonkeyTalk when including its library on an iOS project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, monkey-testing

I am wondering what is [MonkeyTalk](http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/monkeytalk) doing when embedding the static library into an iOS Project. I was trying to record some automated UI tests and I found an undesired behaviour in my app.

I had the need to add the accessibility label to a custom UI component because MonkeyTalk was not automatically recognizing it. When I do so I get a `nil` in a variable that's never taking a `nil` when not adding the accessibility label.

If I change the accessibility label assignment it works some lines after some initialization (ivars synthesized through standard Obj-C 2.0 properties) of the UI component it works...

This doesn't run as expected (Getting a nil when getting an ivar from `_groupViewController`):

```
_groupViewController = [[GroupsViewController alloc] init];

[_groupViewController.view setAccessibilityLabel:kAL_Slider];

// Set _groupViewController ivars through non-custom properties
```

This does:

```
_groupViewController = [[GroupsViewController alloc] init];

// Set _groupViewController ivars through non-custom properties   

[_groupViewController.view setAccessibilityLabel:kAL_Slider];
```

My question is, what is the library doing internally? Does it modify any kind of object internals on runtime?